# Issue With Nested Condition Within @Query in MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

When I run the following query in Mongo Shell, it returns the correct result.

```
db.getCollection('collectionOne').find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          "fieldOne": "statusOne"
        },
        {
          "fieldOne": "statusTwo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "createdAt": { $lt: new Date("1970-01-01").toISOString() }
    },
    {
      "fieldTwo": null
    }
  ]
})
```

But when I use `@Query` on a MongoRepository method, it returns empty result.

```
    @Query(
            value = "{ '$and': [{'fieldTwo': null}, { 'createdAt': { $lt: ?2 } }, { '$or': [{'fieldOne': ?0}, {'fieldOne': ?1}] } ]}"
    )
    List<Entity> findEntities(Status statusOne, Status statusTwo, OffsetDateTime createdDate);
```

Any Ideas what I am missing ?

Comment: May be you need to pass `null` as the parameter for the `fieldTwo`.

Comment: There may be an issue with the date. Can you turn on DEBUG log for ```org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate``` and check what is the query sent to db?

Comment: `createdAt` is String in your database, but Repository receives `OffsetDateTime`

Comment: Valijon, I use MongoConverters for that.
Harshit, The logging is not working for some reason.
prasad_, I think you were right, I ended up hardcoding most of the values in the query (most of them were fixed)